# How to create a dynamic role on Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, rbac

I am trying to implement a multi-tenancy model in Airflow using RBAC. I am on Airflow 2.0.1. The idea is to have a set of base permissions that each tenant has on the Airflow server. But each tenant will get its own role, so I can use access_control at DAG level to only let users of that tenant see the DAG.

Does anyone know how to create a new role by:

1. copying permissions of another pre-defined Role

   OR
2. specifying the permissions, at role creation or after creating an empty role

Edit: I am trying to do this through API or CLI, not the webserver UI. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the airflow STABLE REST API to create a role with predefined permissions
checkout - [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_role]

For example:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/roles" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"actions\":[{\"action\":{\"name\":\"can_read\"},\"resource\":{\"name\":\"Website\"}},{\"action\":{\"name\":\"can_edit\"},\"resource\":{\"name\":\"DAG:tutorial\"}},{\"action\":{\"name\":\"can_create\"},\"resource\":{\"name\":\"Task Instances\"}}],\"name\":\"new_custom_role\"}"
```

You can checkout all permissions here - [airflow permissions](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.1/security/access-control.html#permissions)

Comment: Hey Kaish, thanks for the info! But sadly the roles endpoint is only available for Airflow 1.0, not in the 2.0.

[Airflow 1.0 API](http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_plugins).  
[Airflow 2.0 API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Overview)

Comment: @NikhilPatil, it is available for versions >=Airflow 2.1.0; I'm using it with Airflow 2.1.1
[Airflow 2.1.1 APIs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.1/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/Role)